# Block attendees video in Lync 2013 conference

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma, lync-server-2013

I am trying to create a Lync-Meeting programmatically using UCMA/Lync SDK. While the creation of a conference is pretty straight forward, it is one of my requirements to disable/block the video broadcast of the attendees by default. This can easily be achieved by using the UI (see ["Do you want to limit participation?"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-options-for-Skype-for-Business-Lync-Meetings-f628a0fe-6b94-469b-975c-8852a19bddad?ui=de-DE&rs=en-US&ad=US)) But how can I do this using code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're scheduling a conference and not creating one ad-hoc, since your link says:

> When you’re scheduling your Skype for Business (Lync) Meetings, you can use the default options, which are appropriate for small and casual meetings with coworkers.

When you schedule a conference through UCMA, you pass it an object of type [`ConferenceScheduleInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.conferencemanagement.conferencescheduleinformation_members%28v=office.13%29.aspx). This has a property `Mcus` which controls the allowed MCUs for your conference.

```
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.ApplicationSharing));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.InstantMessaging));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.AudioVideo));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.Meeting));
... etc ...
```

This allows you to control what MCUs are available.

Answer (score 0):

you can not Block video Without Audio. this meaning if dont add McuType.AudioVideo in conference schedule information object then that conference wont have audio and video for all participants.
for your question: should view `CsConferencingPolicy`

Answer (score 0):

From the Lync Client Sdk you can toggle the conference "attendee video mute" by setting the [ConversationProperty.ConferenceVideoHardMute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationproperty_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) on the [Conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversation_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) instance.

Can example of settings the property where "value" is either true/false, where true == mute attendee video and false == unmute attendee video.

```
if (_conversation != null &&
    _conversation.CanSetProperty(ConversationProperty.ConferenceVideoHardMute))
{
    _conversation.BeginSetProperty(ConversationProperty.ConferenceVideoHardMute, value, ar =>
    {
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                _conversation.EndSetProperty(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                 // exception handling
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

or if you prefer a Task based version:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync(_conversation.BeginSetProperty(ConversationProperty.ConferenceVideoHardMute, value, null, null), ar => _conversation.EndSetProperty(ar));
```